# Given a group of 100 people, at minimum how many people were born in the same month?

Tags: combinatorics

By pigeonhole principle we can say that, there is at least one month in which we have more than $\lceil 100/12\rceil$ people. And this is the answer of this question. But I don't understand why $0$ cannot be a answer. Since in any case "at minimum" or "at least" $0$ people are born in same month.

Comment: I believe you mean that there is at least a month in which at least (rather than more than) $\lceil 100/12\rceil$ individuals were born.

Comment: I also think the minimum is $0$.

Comment: @Patricio Yes that's what question was all about. I have written the exact problem statement and I feel like the problem statement is ambiguous.

Comment: This question is terribly ambiguous, what would it mean for "$0$" people to be born in "the same month" anyway? Whose birthdays are you comparing when you don't have anyone to compare with? That , of course, is not your fault @SameerRaj but I think you might want to skip this question as written.

Comment: @sarvesh-ravichandran-iyer Okay I agree about the zero part but even we can put 2 in same month and can say that there is "at minimum" 2 people who are born in same month. I also do think that this question seems ambiguous but almost all my peers never complained about this statement and accepted 9 as the answer. So I came here to clarify my concern about the question.

Comment: It depends on your context. If this came in the context of the "pigeonhole principle" then I'm pretty sure you and all your friends are right. If this question came out of nowhere, or in a set of general problems, I would request you to leave it and move on. If it came in an exam, you can be assured that the question is way too ambiguous to have a clear answer. I'm surprised your peers did not complain, but that's probably *because* the context of "pigeonhole principle" was too obvious for them to read much into the question, like we've done here.

Comment: @sarvesh-ravichandran-iyer Yeah I also think people didn't complained because of the context in which it was going on. But I tried to think more generally then stumbled.

Comment: It is true that the wording is ambiguous.  My interpretation was the$ \lceil 100/12\rceil$ one.  But after reading the OP, I can see the other possible interpretation.